# php function to change css

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to add a piece of code to change css on a page. I added the code to `functions.php` in WordPress. However, it does not seem to work. Since I'm quite new to this there might be something quite basic wrong with the code... Any idea why it might not be working?

```
// This code is added to functions.php
// intro is the class name of the element I'm trying to change
add_action( 'intro', function () {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        ?>
            <style>
                display: none!important;
            </style>
        <?php
    };
    exit;
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work because your style is incorrect. You are missing the selection. What should be set to `display: none !important`? div boxes, the entire body, or ... or ... or ...?

Comment: if you've made an update, please update your question to show what you've changed/tried, and what the new issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by removing `exit;` and targeting an element:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        ?>
            <style>
                .intro{
                    display: none!important;
                }
            </style>
        <?php
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is change the content of the css class which I do not think you can do. Instead a solution would be to assign a css class with the propertied that you want applied to the element e.g.

```
<div class="<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo 'intro';} ?>">
   // Whatever you have here will get the css style applied 
   // if user is logged in
</div>
```

And inn The CSS you have the following

```
.intro{
  display: none!important;
}
```

You can create multiple files for different styles e.g. another class

```
.outro{
  display:initial;
}
```

And you can add it in the code as

```
<div class="<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo 'intro';} else{ echo 'outro';} ?>">
       // Whatever you have here will get the css style applied 
       // if user is logged in and if logged out then outro class will be applied
    </div>
```

Comment: I think the problem with this solution is that it requires to directly add php in a WordPress page, which I don't think is possible in WordPress?

Comment: @Zoe it is possible. That is how the themes are designed. But as long as your answer works all good :).

Comment: @Zoe you make a child theme, and put your custom code in the child-theme/functions.php.